# Shortening a GUID

Tags: character-encoding, base64, guid

We generate a GUID for a document and need to include the GUID in a barcode (Type 29 2D) which is C40 encoded and has the following restrictions.

Can be a max length of 25 characters
Can only use UPPER Alphanumerical characters, no special characters.

I had thought of converting to Base64 but that uses special characters.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [base36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) encoding.

Given that a UUID is only 16 bytes, it should fit into 25 base36 characters.

To demonstrate, here's a small JavaScript snippet that takes the example UUID from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (`123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000`) and converts it to base36:

```js
const guid = BigInt('0x123e4567e89b12d3a456426614174000');
const encoded = guid.toString(36).toUpperCase();

console.log("Encoded: " + encoded); // 12VQJRNXK8WHV3I8QI6QGRLZ4
console.log("Length: " + encoded.length); // 25
```

Comment: I think I'm missing a step, if I just convert a GUID to Base32 (even without the hyphens) it becomes longer in Base32, albeit having the correct character set.

2783a4b160c546338fcaca4314a98558 becomes 

68vkgcv16hh32dhgccuk8dhk6cw6crv1cdgk8cth6hgkje1n6mw0

Comment: I tried that using my code above, and still get a 25 character string for that value: `2C7S5SJ0B8N2JME1Y00AEPPW8`. Are you sure that you're interpreting the UUID as a hex value and not as a string?

Comment: I think that's my problem, I'm not generating the GUID so I do receive it as a string, although I can parse it into a GUID. If I generate a GUID in my test app, it works where I convert the GUID to a byte array and then to Base32 but gives me 26 characters

Comment: Base32? Or base36?

Comment: You should be able to represent all possible values in base36. It's a 128-bit value, which gives you `2^128 = 3.402823669×10³⁸` combinations. 25 base36 characters allow `36^25 = 8.0828×10³⁸` combinations, so double.

Comment: Yep sorry I'd tried Base32 but I'm doing this in VB.NET and struggling to find a way to replicate how you could do it in Java to convert to Base36. I get the GUID's value from an XML and then use that value in the barcode but I can only fit UPPER alpha/numerics and only 25 chars

Comment: You saw that the Wikipedia link in my answer contains a VB.net implementation, right? Not sure if VB.net allows 128-bit integers though... Could probably do it if you convert your 16 bytes to two `ULong`s.

Comment: @Colster 26 letters (A-Z) + 10 digits (0-9) gives 36 possibilities. There might be a library that does base36, or you could just roll your own.